# SQL Table billions of entries - Looking for performance recommendations

Tags: sql, database, performance

I have a huge database and im looking for a right set up. Currently im inserting all my entries in a MongoDB hoping that it works better than MySQL (MySQL does not work for such a huge db).

I made a small python script that search all my text files with multiprocessing. One query takes about 1-2 hours with plain text files (150gb).

Maybe this information helps:
The data is a dictionary (Key, Value but a there are some duplicate keys with different values.

How and which SQL system can I set up to handle such a huge amount of entries and will the queries even be faster than a textfile search?
What would you recommend me?

Comment: 150GB is manageable. Have you examined your indexes and are they optimized for your dataset. You should research partitioning schemes for large tables and full-text searches. This question will likely be closed because the answers for these types of questions tend to be opinion based.

Comment: Even if its opinion based I will be thankful for every opinon because I would not call my self a sql expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions are possible using a RDBMS like MySql, Spark on parquet file or even MongoDB. I don't have have much experience with Mongo so I will weigh on 1st 2 options.

RDBMS - 
1. Shard and Partition the table. This will make your searching h scalable.

2. Index the table on search keys (which needn't be unique) - this will make the lookup faster.
3. Compress the data

If you expect all records to be searched and processed then Shard and Partition will help. If few records to be processed then index will help.

If a lot data is changed then big data system (using Spark) and data lake (using parquet) will help. Spark can parallel process in a far better way than the python script you are using. Parquet will help data be compressed and splittable for parallel processing. It is columnar, so it can be queried on few column without reading whole row data. This option is not good if small amount of data is being changed. My system has around 200GB of data which gets processed (every record is touched) in 20 minutes using a Spark cluster with 20 CPUs and 100GB memory.

Proper Data model helps a lot in performance and scalability, so this needs to be appropriate too.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I will try this out.

Comment: You said you have documents and also key-value pair. Tell me more about the structure. Data model helps a lot in performance and scalability.

Comment: Thats acutally everything. All my data is sorted in keys and values, but a key could appear multiple times with a different value.

Comment: What is stored as value? A document?

Comment: No just 5 more fields with about 10 characters each

Comment: If you decide to use parquet file for storage then you can store an array of values for a key on the same row.